# Python - Function Calls involving Object Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, scope, initialization

Suppose I have a parent class `foo` and an inheriting class `bar` defined as such:

```
class foo(object):

   def __init__(self, args):
      for key in args.keys():
         setattr(self, key, args[key])
      self.subinit()

   def subunit(self):
      pass

   ...
```

---

```
import math

class bar(foo):

   def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
      args = locals()
      del args['self']
      super(foo, self).__init__(args)

   def subunit(self):
      super(foo, self).subinit()
      self.arg1 = math.radians(self.arg1)
      self.arg2 = math.radians(self.arg2)
      ...

   ...
```

I have `bar` overriding the function `subinit` as it was defined by the parent class `foo`. However, since I am executing the line `self.subinit()` from inside the superclass constructor. I'm concerned that the `subinit` definition for `foo` will be used instead of the overridden `subinit` for `bar`. So my question, then, is this: What is the scope of execution here? If I call `subinit` from the superclass constructor, will it work in the scope of the totality of the instance and call `bar.subinit()` or will it work in the scope of the function and call `foo.subinit()`

Comment: What about trying it out?

Comment: Well, I haven't done it yet because I wanted to see if someone else knew first. But since you insist...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I ran a test after adjusting the example a little:

```
class foo(object):

   def __init__(self, args):
      for key in args.keys():
         setattr(self, key, args[key])
      self.subinit()

   def subinit(self):
      pass
```

---

```
class bar(foo):

   def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
      args = locals()
      del args['self']
      super(self.__class__, self).__init__(args)

   def subinit(self):
      print self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3
```

The scope appears to be in the totality of the object, not just within the superclass. Therefore, `bar.subinit()` is getting called. Good to know.